# Maven package does not exist

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, compiler-errors, dependencies

I have been trying to re-compile an application that uses Hadoop and Spark from the Cloudera distribution 5.4.0 with Maven, doing a mvn clean package command, and I keep getting the following error:

> [ERROR]
>   /.../src/main/java/org/apache/sysml/runtime/instructions/spark/functions/SparkListener.java:[35,33]
>   package org.apache.spark.ui.scope does not exist

These are the relevant parts of the **pom.xml** file, with properties, dependencies and repositories.

```
<properties>
    <hadoop.version>2.6.0-cdh5.4.0</hadoop.version>
            <spark.version>1.3.0-cdh5.4.0</spark.version>
    <antlr.version>4.3</antlr.version>

    <!-- OS-specific JVM arguments for running integration tests -->
    <integrationTestExtraJVMArgs />
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spark-assembly_2.10</artifactId>
                    <version>${spark.version}</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spark-yarn_2.10</artifactId>
                    <version>${spark.version}</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>

    <!-- To support dataframe in mlcontext -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Adding Gauva version 14.0.1 to workaround conflict between spark and hadoop dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>14.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-app</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wink</groupId>
        <artifactId>wink-json4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>stax</groupId>
        <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr4</artifactId>
        <version>${antlr.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>antlr-runtime</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr4-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>${antlr.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Libraries for yarn integration -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-yarn-api</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-yarn-common</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-yarn-client</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-common</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

    <repositories>
            <repository>
                    <id>cloudera</id>
                    <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
            </repository>
    </repositories>
```

Apparently, the inclusion of dependency spark-core should include the package **org.apache.spark.ui.scope**.
Does anyone know what can be the cause of this problem and how to solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: why so many dependencies are in provided scope? even junit?

Comment: I just modified the pom.xml to change the version of Hadoop and Spark from the original one, and they had this scope in the original file..

Comment: If you have change version of these libraries ... probably these libraries are evolved and their api changed. The used classes may be moved and refactored. Check your source code and the library to make sure used classes still exist

Comment: you can check proper maven dependency [here] (http://mvnrepository.com/) with specific version.